# Замена удаления строки на изменение значения атрибута в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Работаю в MySQL. Нужно заменить удаление строки(при действии оператора DELETE) на смену значения атрибута status. Допустим у нас в строке есть атрибут status = 0. При удалении он должен изменяться на status = 1, а сама строчка должна остаться в таблице. Я так понимаю это нужно сделать через триггеры, но в MySQL нет эквивалента INSTEAD OF, который бы заменил удаление на изменение значения атрибута. Идей у меня никаких нет...

Текст самого задания:

> Добавить в структуру таблицы Проекты поле, которое хранит статус проекта (0 — Актуальный, 1 — Завершенный). Реализовать в виде триггера следующее требование — при удалении строки сделать так, чтобы строка не удалялась, а в ней изменялось поле статуса, устанавливалось значение = 1.

Comment: т.е. вы не можете поменять в коде вызов `DELTE` на `UPDATE` и вам нужно перехватить `DELETE` и вместо этого сделать `UPDATE`?

Comment: Вроде того. Мне нужно перехватывать DELETE и из него как-то сделать UPDATE. Это учебное задание и оно особо никакого смысла не имеет.

Comment: Вы можете указать в вопросе все задание без купюр?

Comment: Да, могу. Сейчас это сделаю.

Comment: Согласно вот этому https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159670/how-can-i-override-the-mysql-delete-command-to-update-a-field-rather-than-to-rem (и другим подобным ответам) можно подать сигнал, который при этом не критическая ошибка. Но это надо конечно проверить на вашем приложении, как оно среагирует

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7595714/5741205)